# Codes for Wilcoxon matched paired test with scatter plot

Tags: r, wilcoxon-signed-rank

How can I modify the following codes in order to get a Wilcoxon matched paired test with **scatter plot**?

```
library("ggpubr")
ggboxplot(meant, x = "event", y = "temperature", 
      color = "event", palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),
      order = c("control", "grooming"),
      ylab = "temperature", xlab = "event")
library("PairedData")
control <- subset(meant,event == "control", temperature,
             drop = TRUE)
grooming<- subset(meant,event == "grooming", temperature,
            drop = TRUE)
library(PairedData)
pd <- paired(control, grooming)
plot(pd, type = "profile") + theme_bw()
res <- t.test(temperature ~ event, data = meant, paired = TRUE)
res
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: "Code" is a mass noun/uncountable noun, it doesn't need an 's' (any more than you write "rices" or "waters" when talking about a mass of rice or water). I don't know why adding the s has suddenly proliferated in the last few years, since the word was in wide use in this context for about 5 decades before that happened.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b but I speak 4 languages and sometimes I can get very confused about grammatical rules, especially when more than one lecturer say "codes" repeatedly. You should give a look into WordReference forum, your comments would be appreciated there :)

Comment: It's not just you; many native speakers have started doing it lately. Your English was so good I took you for a native English speaker. For a non-native speaker, it would not be something I'd bother you about.